# hresult e_fail error using christoc template

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, dotnetnuke

I have setup a new development environment using

WIN 8.1, VS2013, Telerik controls q3 2014, Dotnetnuke 7.03.04, Json.net 6.08 and latest DNN 7 Project Templates V4 for VS2013.

When I create a new DAL2 project and open view.ascx in design mode then I get "hresult e_fail..." error for the rptItemList control. I am also not able to put a control in design mode. If I write the control in the source and go back to design mode then I get the same error for the created control..

If I create a new ASP.NET web application project I have NO problems adding controls and no errors.

Please help.

Kind regards,

Henk

Comment: What is the name of your project and Solution? Do you happen to have underscores in them?

Answer (score 0):

I restored the Discussions tab on Codeplex and dug through the posts there.

https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/discussions/355503

Looks like it is either caused by

- Underscore or Dashes in the project/solution name
- Bad configuration in IIS, make sure you don't have a virtualdirectory/application on the desktopmodules or the module folder in IIS.

Comment: I checked the suggestions but everything seems ok. Luckily I am able to sove it by reinstalling the dotnetnuke site again. The steps I did: delete the website, delete the database and add a new database again, delete t everything under \websites\dnndev.me and copy agina

Comment: I checked the suggestions but everything seems ok. I can login in the dnn site. Luckily I am able to sove it by reinstalling the dotnetnuke site again. The steps I did: 1. delete the website and create again the website, 2. delete the database and add a new database again, 3. delete  everything under \websites\dnndev.me and copy again the files from the install directory,  4. Install dotnetnuke (see youre last video 4 for installing dotnetnuke 7.x). I was happy that the error does not occur when creating a new dotnet module (dal7).